# Validating three text fields with jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have three text fields which are to be filled up with numbers. The total of these three text fields should always add up to 100. I'm using the jQuery Validation plugin to ease things and have used `.addmethod()` to validate this case.

What I've tried: http://jsfiddle.net/NcW9V/

--the code posted below is a copy of what is found in the jsfiddle--
My code for the jQuery:

```
//show the percentage
        $("#airPercent, #seaPercent, #landPercent").change(function(){
            var sPerct = $('#seaPercent').val();
            var lPerct = $('#landPercent').val();
            var perct = $('#airPercent').val();
            var newTotal = parseInt(perct) + parseInt(lPerct) + parseInt(sPerct);
            $("#totalP").empty();
            $("#totalP").text(newTotal);
        });

//the validator     
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkModePerct", function(value) {
        total = parseInt($('#airPercent').val()) + parseInt($('#seaPercent').val()) + parseInt($('#landPercent').val());
        return total == 100;
        }, "Please only enter a sum total of 100%");

$("#contact-form").validate(
    {
    });
```

The HTML markup:

```
<form action="lane" method="post" id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal">

        <legend>Mode of Transportation:</legend>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Air</th>
                            <th>Sea</th>
                            <th>Land</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Percentage</td>
                            <td class="span3">
                                <input type="text" class="span1" name="airPercent" id="airPercent" value="0" class="required  checkModePerct"/>%
                            </td>
                            <td class="span3">
                                <input type="text" class="span1" name="seaPercent" id="seaPercent" value="0" class="required  checkModePerct"/>%
                            </td>
                            <td class="span3">                          
                                <input type="text" class="span1" name="landPercent" id="landPercent" value="0" class="required  checkModePerct"/>%      
                            </td>
                            <td class="span3">
                                <div id="totalP">
                                    0
                                </div>%
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
         </table>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

I've gone through a number of other examples but the closest I can find is http://jsfiddle.net/wtmv3/. I played with the code but can't get it to work as I'm not sure what `jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.checkTotal` does. There doesn't seem to be any information about it either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You posted three different versions of code, one in the OP and two jsFiddles.  I picked the one closest to what you described...

> *"I have three text fields which are to be filled up with numbers. The total of these three text fields should always add up to 100.  I'm using the jQuery Validation plugin..."*

**Working Code:  http://jsfiddle.net/K3S5S/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //percentage  // I made no changes to your '.change()' handler
    $("#airPercent, #seaPercent, #landPercent").change(function () {
        var sPerct = $('#seaPercent').val();
        var lPerct = $('#landPercent').val();
        var perct = $('#airPercent').val();
        var newTotal = parseInt(perct) + parseInt(lPerct) + parseInt(sPerct);
        $("#totalP").empty();
        $("#totalP").text(newTotal);
    });

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkTotal", function (value) {
        // if you need to check total of three fields, then add up all three!
        total = parseFloat($('#airPercent').val()) + parseFloat($('#seaPercent').val()) + parseFloat($('#landPercent').val());
        return total == 100;  // returns true/false if total is 100 or not
    }, "Total must add up to 100%!");

    $("#contact-form").validate({
        rules: {  // declare your rule based on field "name"
            airPercent: {
                required: true,
                checkTotal: true
            },
            seaPercent: {
                required: true,
                checkTotal: true
            },
            landPercent: {
                required: true,
                checkTotal: true
            }
        },
        groups: {  // combine all three messages into one
            percent: "airPercent seaPercent landPercent"
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
             // place the message after the total
             error.insertAfter(  $('#totalP') );  
        }
    });

});
```

- You don't need the `classRuleSettings` and I'm not even sure if it's currently a valid method.  Quote:  *"There doesn't seem to be any information about it either."* ~ That should be a red flag that it's likely not a valid option or method.  It appears to simply say the custom rule is `true` when declared as a `class`, however by using any custom rule within a field `class`, you are declaring the rule as `true`.  In other words, it's either doing nothing or it's superfluous... just remove it.
- You must declare your custom rule `checkTotal` on *all three* fields.  I have declared all rules within the `.validate()` method.  You can move them into the field classes if you want... either way is valid.
- I used the `groups` option to combine all error messages into one.
- I used the `errorPlacement` callback to place the error message in a more logical location, right next to the total field.  Adjust as needed.
- I did not see any mistakes in your code, just a lack of implementation.  Refer to documentation:   http://jqueryvalidation.org

Comment: Thanks. I was rather confused as I read quite a few tutorials and many of them had different implementations. Was worried that adding checkTotal: true to the rules for each field would only cause it to be executed in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/UR4sX/

You will notice a couple of things:

1. if(sPerct > 0 && lPerct  > 0 && perct > 0){ - this is so the validation only fires when all 3 boxes are filled out - otherwise it would be annoying
2. The if(newtotal !== 100) section - at the moment it only shows pass or fail - you would need to add code to stop it firing if not valid in here.

   ```
       $("#airPercent, #seaPercent, #landPercent").change(function(){
       var sPerct = $('#seaPercent').val();
       var lPerct = $('#landPercent').val();
       var perct = $('#airPercent').val();

       var newTotal = parseInt(perct) + parseInt(lPerct) + parseInt(sPerct);

       if(sPerct > 0 && lPerct  > 0 && perct > 0){
           if (newTotal !== 100){
               $('#valid').html("Please enter amounts totalling 100");
           }else{
               $('#valid').html("pass");
           }


       }


       $("#totalP").empty();
       $("#totalP").text(newTotal);
   });
   ```

Comment: That's the only part that _was already_ working. The OP wants to know how to implement the jQuery Validate plugin, not how to manually validate it as you've done.

Comment: Actually the OP says they have added jQuery validator for ease - but does not specifically say they want to use it - my answer does the job and with less over-head than jQuery validate - the world doesn't run on plugins you know! :-D

Comment: Quote:  _"the world doesn't run on plugins you know!"_  ~ How ironic for you to mention the overhead of using plugins while your answer unnecessarily depends on jQuery for simple JS tasks... a "plugin" itself.

Comment: not starting a slanging match - he is using jQuery already - the jQuery validator uses more processing power than my answer - simple as - i have upvoted your answer - chill out we are here to help others not make sure everyone picks our answer!

Comment: Thank-you.  Back on-topic... whether he's already using jQuery has nothing to do with what your code is doing.  When you call `$('#airPercent').val()` instead of `document.getElementById('airPercent').value`, you are _adding_ to the overhead.

Comment: to Graham Ritchie: How do you tell which jQuery would cause more over-head?
@Sparky is document.getElementById('airPercent').value lighter than using $('#airPercent').val()? Because when another question in stackoverflow seems to say that there isn't much difference in using either..

Comment: I can answer both - getelementbyID has the least over-head over $('#val) - the point (that Sparky missed) is that manually checking the values over using the built in jQuery function reduces over-head as the jQuery validator isn't very efficient. Sparkys answer is better for maintainability I was just showing how to manually validate.